# Facebook SDK on Android app, Works on emulator but on phone will just keeps on loading forever

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk, loading

I have followed facebooks tutorial and setup the sso key and have integrated the sdk into my code. After logging into facebook , the facebook.authorize it brings me to a new screen which just says "loading" and sits there.

It can works on emulator but not on my desire HD,
I've tried add ",Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH" , it doesn't work for me.

Image is just has a message says "loading..."

thanks a lot!

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("MyAppID");
String id,name;
TextView t1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);

    }

        facebook.authorize(this,new String[] {"user_about_me"},new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                 GET();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });

}
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

 public void GET(){
    try {
        JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me"));

        if(json1 != null)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<json1.length();i++)
            {
                id = json1.getString("id");                     
                name = json1.getString("name");                 
            }
        }

        t1.setText(id + "," + name);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

   }
```

Comment: have you confirmed that your phone is connected to the internet?

Comment: once check in your phone , inbuilt facebook app is working or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You have written this line ...

Facebook facebook = new Facebook("appid");

The string should not be "appid" but a real app id from facebook.

Login to your account and get a facebook Id from here ...

developers.facebook.com/apps/?action=create

Comment: I found "FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH" on the Internet, I don't know what value it is.  I tried your suggestion and it just bring a new white window after loading.  I will refresh my code later to show.

Comment: I've tried -1 in parameters , it bring a new window with white after loading.  It can works on emulator but not on my desire HD. thanks!    Would you mind give me your email , I'll send image about my problem.